# implementation of a simulated disk for an instructional operating system?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-disk

I am working on an instructional operating system(IOS). This IOS runs on a simulator(multi2sim) which inturns run on host operating system(linux). For host OS, "simulator+IOS+user process"(user process that runs on IOS) works as a single process.

I have specifications like :

```
NO_OF_HEADS = 2
NO_OF_SECTORS = 18
NO_OF_TRACKS = 80
```

Now i need to design a simulated disk so that it simulates a real disk.This simulated disk will be used for storing the swap space of processes(C program executables) as well as the files and directories of the file system..?

Can anyone help me in accomplishing this task ? From where exactly should I start..?
what should be my first step..?